# Multiple Fragments best practice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Guidelines) about using Fragments.

There is an example for how to handle multiple Fragments on a tablet and handset with separate Activities for each Fragment (long story short):

With each item of ListFragment 'A', a new Activity for displaying Fragment 'B' is started.

What is the advantage of using separate Activities for each Fragment instead of using Transactions?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to port your app to phone where fragaments might not be used since the screen is too small to show 2 fragments next to each other - using activities lets you port it quite fast - just need to open another screen for each fragment instead of showing fragments simlutaneously

Actually that is what is meant in the "Design Philosophy" section of the first link you gave

Comment: I disagree (see my answer). And said docs does not indicate that approach (of using many activities) as any better. It's just badly written example in docs.

Answer (score 0):

I see none. If my app runs on tablet I put more fragments on the screen as there's room for this and I got just one activity in which I replace fragments when needed. When it is launched on the phone I got less fragments I still follow that pattern - I got single activity and replace fragments in it. I see benefits of that approaches vs using many activities like less flickering, have one logic for whole app.

Comment: In the meantime I've read a lot of other threads about similar topics and tested a little bit by myself. My experiences until now are that handle multiple fragments in one activity in combination with separated layouts is very flexible.